# the_modified_time showing wrong date

Tags: timestamp

I have an wordpress self-hosted installation that is over 10 years old. I was updating the template files to show the last modified date instead of the published date for my posts.

Old snippet: `<time datetime="<?php the_time('c');?>"> <?php the_time('j F Y'); ?></time>`

New snippet: `<time datetime="<?php the_modified_time('c');?>"><?php the_modified_time('j F Y'); ?>`

Here’s where it got weird. Every post that was modified before 6 februari 2021 shows the date 6 februari 2021. Every post that got updated after 6 februari 2021 shows the correct date.

I double checked this. There are posts that haven’t been updated since 2014 or 2011, yet they show 6 februari 2021. I even went into phpMyAdmin and the post_modified field shows the correct date (not 6 februari 2021).

Does anyone have an idea what it causing this or how to fix this? I have some suspects:

- I’m using older php version: 7.2.34
- I’m using an old sql server (WP site diagnose says so)
- I vagely remember doing a sort of database update. Yoast SEO promted me to do something for indexing purposes.

Comment: What happened on February the 6th? Note that it may not be possible to identify the cause given that this happened in the past, this is more of an open investigation than a specific question

Comment: I may have done this: https://yoast.com/help/why-does-yoast-seo-ask-to-index-a-sites-seo-data/ because at the same date, I published an article and then probably got the notification. This is the direction I'm looking into right now.

Comment: so on February the 6th, something updated all your posts, you'll have to ask Yoast support or in a Yoast community if indexing a sites SEO data would cause post modified times to be updated

Comment: @TomJNowell They say in the question that the dates are correct in the database.

Comment: do you have a link to the question?

Comment: In the DB the table wp_posts has rows with all posts. Each post has a post_modified field that displays the correct data. But, the DB also has a table wp_yoast_indexable that also has rows of posts. These posts have a field post_modified with the incorrect date (6feb). So, I'm looking at yoast support now.